# 'Size' is imported from both 'dart:ffi' and 'dart:ui' Flutter 3

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading my flutter from 2.10.5 to 3.0.0, I have those errors on my android studio and the project don't build anymore on windows 10.
How can I solve this problems.
Thanks

```
'Size' is imported from both 'dart:ffi' and 'dart:ui'.
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using bitsdojo_window package?

Comment: @BehzodFaiziev yes! the problem is the project is working correctly before my upgrade to Flutter 3

Comment: For me it's same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bitsdojo_window package seems to have issues when Flutter 3 was introduced. One of possible ways is to run this command on your terminal

```
dart fix --apply
```

and

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Comment: The problem persists even when I'm running this command.

Comment: One of the possible solutions is discussed  [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103571#issuecomment-1125705625):

Comment: @LapaNyAinaTanjona also try to run this command flutter pub upgrade

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of Flutter 3.0. This package needs to get updated for Flutter 3.0
check [This Link](https://github.com/bitsdojo/bitsdojo_window/issues/171) for the answer it requires an update which the developer said he's working on it

Comment: Upgrading `bitsdojo_window:` to version `^0.1.2` helped, thanks!